# Почему создавать асинхронные "обертки" для синхронных методов считается неправильным?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

Не могу понять, чем плох подобный код:

```
public ICollection<Product> GetAllProducts() { //getting data from DB }

public async Task<ICollection<Product>> GetAllProductsAsync()
{
    return await Task<ICollection<Product>>.Factory.StartNew(GetAllProducts)
}
```

Comment: Кем считается? Впервые об этом слышу.

Comment: @ixSci, я, в общем-то тоже впервые слышу, но ведь плюсов у  такого обёртывания не видно.

Comment: @ixSci разработчиками `async/await` :).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Я не буду отвечать от себя, а просто приведу слова разработчиков .NET. В концов концов кто как не они являются истиной в последней инстанции о том, как что-то должно работать.

Ниже очень краткое содержимое поста ["Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?"](https://web.archive.org/web/20160718141855/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx) от разработчиков async/await и создателей [TAP](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19957). Знаете язык -- читайте, не знаете -- переводите Гуглом. Но обязательно читайте.

---

### Асинхронность

Два главных преимущества асинхронности -- это масштабируемость и разгрузка основного потока (отзывчивость UI, параллелизм). Разным типам приложений, как правило, нужны разные преимущества: серверным приложениям нужна масштабируемость, UI приложениям -- разгрузка.

### Масштабируемость

Возможность запускать синхронные методы как асинхронные не увеличивает масштабируемость, поскольку количество затрачиваемых ресурсов остается тем же самым -- вместо текущего потока выполняется в другом потоке. Масштабируемость приложений достигается за счет того, что при правильной асинхронности те же самые ресурсы выполняют бОльшее количество работы.

### Разгрузка

В случае с повышением отзывчивости UI и запуском кода в параллельных потоках оборачивание синхронного кода в асинхронный -- это то, что нужно.

### Дискуссия

Команда разработчиков .NET в [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19957) не рекомендует держать в API асинхронные методы, которые просто оборачивают синхронные.

Как уже было сказано, для того, чтобы улучшить масштабируемость, код должен быть действительно асинхронным -- т.е. исходный синхронный код нужно переделывать. В случае разгрузки -- исходный синхронный код не нуждается в переделках. При этом если вы предоставляете в API только синхронную версию, вы получаете некоторые бонусы:

- Меньше методов -- меньше головной боли. Разработчикам нужно меньше сопровождать и тестировать. Пользователям API -- меньше мучаться выбором, какой же метод использовать в каждом конкретном случае.
- По гайдлайну все содержащиеся в API методы должны быть по-настоящему асинхронными. Т.е. видя асинхронный метод в API, пользователь API должен быть уверен, что его использование улучшит масштабируемость.
- Выбор того, запускать ли синхронный метод асинхронным образом, остается за пользователем. Если он может "потерпеть"/позволяют обстоятельства -- он запустит метод синхронно. Если ему нужна будет отзывчивость -- он запустит метод асинхронно.

Главный вывод: **API не должен врать и вводить в заблуждение**.

---

От себя лишь скажу, что пока пишешь программы для себя, или пока пишешь код, который больше никто не использует, эти доводы могут показаться пустыми. Но поверьте, при серьезной разработке в команде, а тем более при создании библиотек, которыми пользуются множество разработчиков, эти правила оказываются очень полезными.

Также стоит добавить, что речь в посте выше идет *о публичном API*. Степень публичность может быть различна -- это может быть библиотека, которую устанавливают сотнями с нугета, или это могут быть ваши коллеги, которые пользуются разработанным вами компонентом. Важно лишь, чтобы публичный API не вводил в заблуждение.

Утверждение "async over sync -- это плохо" ни в коей мере не относится ко всему коду. Потому что, например, если в полностью синхронном коде начинают использовать асинхронные методы, то понятно, что пока приложение полностью не будет "пронизано" `async/await`, в коде будут встречаться "стыки": асинхронные обертки синхронных методов. Это нормально, это рабочий процесс. Важно понимать, что **async over sync должен являться либо вынужденной мерой (в случае разгрузки), либо временной мерой (в случае смешения), но не нормой**.

Дело в том, что любая вещь (хоть фича языка, хоть бытовой прибор) должна быть сделана так, что бы ей было легко пользоваться правильно и сложно пользоваться неправильно. К сожалению, основное достоинство `async/await` -- легкое написание асинхронного кода -- является одновременно и его недостатком. Например потому, что можно легко предоставить асинхронную обертку для синхронного кода. Это может привести к тому, что разработчик может в пару к любому синхронному методу предоставлять асинхронную обертку. Если же вспомнить предыдущие шаблоны асинхронного программирования в .NET -- Asynchronous Programming Model (методы `BeginXXX`/`EndXXX`) и Event-based Asynchronous Pattern (метод `XXXAsync` и событие `XXXCompleted`) -- то в них *значительно сложнее* сделать асинхронную обертку для синхронного метода. И следующей после мысли "А давай-ка я сделаю еще и асинхронный вариант" будет мысль "Да ну его, кому надо, сами сделают". Т.е. эти модели заставляли хорошенько подумать, а действительно ли нужна асинхронная обертка. При использование `async/await` этот барьер отсутствует, поэтому разработчики фичи вынуждены об этом активно говорить и напоминать.

Comment: _"Если он может потерпеть -- он запустит метод асинхронно"_ - синхронно же?

Comment: @Qwertiy да, спасибо.

Comment: Разработчики той или иной фичи языка *никогда* не являются «истиной в последней инстанции» в вопросах дизайна. Хотя я согласен с конкретно этими аргументами, есть и другие случаи, такие как старое API и прочие вещи, которые ты строишь не с нуля, а по какому-то каркасу и вводить правило: искусственные асинхронные методы это плохо — глупо. Асинхронное программирование родилось задолго до async/await и не MS всех «жизни учить», в этом плане.

Comment: @ixSci обновил ответ. И да, речь ведь в вопросе не об асинхронном программировании *вообще*, а всего лишь об `async/await`. Так что насчет "никогда не являются" я не был бы столь категоричен.

Comment: `async/await` это современный метод реализации асинхронного программирования и в вопросе тоже, собственно, речь идёт о нём. Тем более, что `async/await` ничего нового не создают, они просто делают код удобным — они не добавляют ничего нового, поэтому говорить о том, что в контексте async/await рассуждения будут другими, считаю неправильным

Comment: @ixSci обновил ответ еще раз. Простите, что я таким образом дискутирую с вами :).

Comment: @andreycha хороший ответ, а как все-таки правильно сделать асинхронную версию метода GetAllProducts, если вариант c `await Task<ICollection<Product>>.Factory.StartNew(GetAllProducts)` плох?

Comment: @sp7 никак. Пусть клиент сам его оборачивает, если ему нужно. Либо переписывать метод на по-настоящему асинхронный, с использованием асинхронного API, но это не всегда возможно.

Comment: @andreycha а что значит `по-настоящему асинхронный` как это будет выглядеть в коде для данного случая? Ведь для того что бы не блокировать текущий поток, в любом случае "тяжелую работу" нужно перенести в другой поток.

Comment: @sp7 использующий асинхронный API, предоставленный библиотекой/системой. Чтобы сходить к диску или сети, не нужно никакие потоки, пока диск или сеть отвечают.

Comment: @andreycha но асинхронный API, который предоставляет система так же создает внутри себя `Task` для асинхронных операций. Например, https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/IO/Stream.cs#L960 Мне кажется, что это разумно, создать новый поток если, предположим, для моего случая нет готовых асинхронных операций.

Comment: @sp7 это неудачный пример, поскольку этот класс -- просто заглушка. И на уровне же системы (ОС) нет никаких тасков, там есть асинхронный API, который классы BCL используют и [выставляют наружу таски](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/IO/Stream.cs#L960). Сгрузить синхронное выполнение в отдельный поток, безусловно, имеет смысл в некоторых ситуациях. Смысл в том, чтобы предоставить это клиенту. А не предоставлять якобы асинхронный метод, который на деле не является по-настоящему асинхронным.

Answer (score 3):

Как минимум тем, что тратятся лишние ресурсы.

Например, Windows поддерживает операции асинхронного ввода-вывода, поэтому для ожидания куска данных не надо создавать новый поток и отправлять его в спячку - система сама уведомит о завершении чтения.

Аналогично может быть и с другими операциями.

Если ты предоставляешь async-версию, то от неё ожидается более оптимальное использование ресурсов, чем от обычной. В конце концов, вызывающий код может сам запустить обычную операцию через `StartNew`. И, если ему надо 10 таких операций, он их запусти всей пачкой, а не за 10 раз. И не потратит на побочную работу в 10 раз больше, чем при том, что каждый async-метод делает StartNew.

Answer (score 3):

async/await, в зависимости от типа приложения, даёт два разных бонуса:

- В Desktop (WPF/Winforms) этот механизм позволяет перенести часть работы в фоновый поток. UI поток в этом случае - ценный ресурс, и асинхронность путем запуска фонового потока вполне имеет смысл. Но в таком случае проще написать весь вызываемый код синхронно, а обёртки сделать на самом верху.
- в ASP.NET UI потока нет. Код обработки запроса выполняется на потоке из пула. Ваш код освобождает этот поток (при условии что на самом верху у вас используется асинхронный контроллер). Но при этом выедает еще один поток из пула для выполнения операции. Т.е. ваш код как использовал поток из пула, так и использует. Но теперь вы платите дополнительные расходы на "асинхронность".

В случае ASP.NET может возникнуть соблазн запустить таким образом два обращения к базе в рамках одного потока (ака "распараллелить"). Вот только проблема в том, что в ASP.NET потоки и ядра - это ценный ресурс. Если серверу для выполнения запроса придётся загрузить два ядра - то он сможет обработать в два раза меньше одновременных запросов. Т.е. на девелоперский машине вы получите ускорение, а на сервере под нагрузкой - нет.

При правильном использовании - протягивании асинков от сетевых или дисковых операций - async/await позволит вам сэкономить потоки. При неправильном - наоборот, наоборот, потратит их.

Т.е. могут быть случаи, когда от обертывания будет значительный выигрыш, но делать это надо очень аккуратно - иначе вы получите совершенно противоположный ожидаемому эффект.

Comment: Если серверу для выполнения запроса придётся загрузить два ядра - то он сможет обработать в два раза меньше одновременных запросов. Т.е. на девелоперский машине вы получите ускорение, а на сервере под нагрузкой - нет.

Если у сервера будет хватать ресурсов на параллельные запросы, клиент получит ответ быстрее. Не будет хватать, получит примерно так же. Так что выгода есть.

Comment: @Vitalii сервера в продакшене не должны простаивать - т.е. если у сервера хватает ресурсов на параллельные запросы - значит вы переплачиваете за железо в два раза. На моем текущем проекте пытались "распараллеливать" выполнение запроса - и это сильно ударило по производительности. Причем производительность продакшена до/после действительно меряли, а не просто оценивали "на глаз". Оказалось, что "примерно так же" - слишком оптимистичная оценка.

Comment: @Vitalii потоки требуют синхронизации, иногда требуют времени на старт (если в пуле свободных нет), требуют памяти (от мегабайта на поток). и при этом никак не решают проблемы с основным узким местом - сетевыми вызовами и прочим io-bound. Т.е. "получит примерно так же" - это очень оптимистичная оценка. на практике - "получит гарантированно медленнее, чем без распараллеливания" :)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и за то что поделились опытом. Получается что мы можем получить выиграш при недогрузе системы (и платить повышенную стоимость) и получить проблему при полной загрузке когда выделение потоков будет стоить нам ресурсов которых у нас нет. Получается что распарелливание имеет смысл тогда, когда нам важна скорость и мы готовы ее оплатить, просто подняв верхнюю планку мощности сервера. Я правильно размышляю?

Comment: @Vitalii Примерно так, но на практике стоит явно мерять разницу для каждого конкретного изменения. Обычно гораздо проще (дешевле) не тратить время на кодинг, а взять процессор / vm подороже. К примеру, на том же azure можно просто поменять вируталки с A на D / D2, и получить прирост производительности в два раза :) Распараллеливание должно быть последним шагом, когда у вас действительно CPU-bound код, и остальные варианты оптимизации уже не помогают.

Answer (score 1):

```
//getting data from DB
```

за этим комментарием вероятнее всего стоит работа с сетью или файлом, данные операции следует выполнять асинхронно.

Автор кода делает асинхронную обертку над синхронным методом, который по природе должен быть асинхронным.

Допускаю единственный сценарий, почему так иногда случается: интерфейс для запроса к БД синхронный, а интерфейс, который реализует автор, требует асинхронной сигнатуры.

Даже если так, то логичнее выглядит

```
    public Task<ICollection<Product>> GetAllProductsAsync()
    {
        return Task.FromResult(GetAllProducts());
    }
```

Comment: Не логичнее. Правило "нельзя блокировать вызывающий поток в асинхронном методе" сильнее чем обсуждаемое.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, а не могли бы более подробно пояснить? И как лучше выйти из ситуации, описанной автором ответа?

Comment: @klutch1991 у вас там сверху три ответа, причем один из них - принятый