# Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult>" в "System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
public async Task<ActionResult> SelectType(LotViewModel vm)
{
    //todo: изменить на нормальный listbox
    var types = await Task.Run(()=>UnitOfWork.LotTypes.GetList());

    ViewBag.Types = types;

    if (vm.Type == null)
    {
        return PartialView("SelectType", vm);
    }

    return Steps(vm);
}
```

решил переделать метод контроллера под async/await, как показано в примере http://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/3.8.php но он не хочет компилироваться и выдает мне"
Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "System.Threading.Tasks.Task" в "System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult"." Я немного не пойму в чем проблема вроде все как в примере, как сделать правильно подскажите пожалуйста?

Comment: А на какую строчку ругается?

Comment: Это неправильное использование async. Почему - подробно расписано в http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/498404/177221. Конкретно в asp.net оно вам ничего не даст, и только добавит тормозов.

Comment: Судя по всему, `Steps` у вас возвращает `Task<T>`? Приведите его код в теле вопроса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего `Steps` у вас объявлен как

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Steps(LotViewModel vm)
{
   ...
}
```

В таком случае вам стоит возвращать не результат вызова Steps (еще выполняющийся Task), а ждать его завершения через await:

```
return await Steps(vm);
```

---

Стоит отметить, что вызов вида

```
var types = await Task.Run(()=>UnitOfWork.LotTypes.GetList());
```

на самом деле просто перебрасывает работу из одного потока из пула (потока, в котором выполняется запрос) в другой поток из того же пула (который выделяется под `Task.Run`). Т.е. на самом деле этот код ничего не экономит (вы как используете поток из пула во время работы вашего кода, так и используете), но добавляет накладных расходов, и, потенциально, дает лаг на старт нового потока из пула, если там не окажется свободного в момент вызова `Run`.

В ASP.NET асинхронность приносит реальную пользу только при протягивании `async` от самих сетевых или дисковых операций - тогда поток действительно освобождается и может выполнять другой запрос. Т.е. если вы протяните `Task`/`async` например, от вызовов EF `ToListAsync` (которые протянут их от вызовов `SqlCommand.ExecuteXXXAsync`) - то вы получите экономию потоков. А если вы просто запустите еще один поток через `Task.Run` - вы получите расходы в чистом виде.

Comment: public ActionResult Steps(LotViewModel vm)

Comment: Объявлен он так, я просто прочитал главу приведенную в вопросе и там сказано что при обращении к бд лучше обертывать в асинк эвеит, UnitOfWork.LotTypes.GetList() это простая обертка  public IEnumerable<LotType> GetList()
        {
            return db.LotTypes;
        }
Ну вот я и решил попробовать но как видите не получилось, и я не понимаю почему, сейчас прочитаю то что вы кинули про неправильное использование async await, и попробую что нибудь написать.

Comment: Я понял что смысла в этом мало, но как сами видели я следовал тому что написано в "учебнике", оказалось что там не верно написано, другой вопрос как ускорить иначе? Или оставить просто синхронный контроллер в покое и не трогать его?

Comment: @NickitaDavidenko значит компилятор ругается на какую-то другую строчку. Ускорить в вашем случае - не получится. Для принятия решения в if нужен результат из базы. Т.е. как не крутитесь - код if будет выполнен в то же самое время.  Максимум - можно сэкономить поток во время выборки из базы - для этого нужно делать асинхронным ваш метод GetList, и в нем вызывать LotTypes.ToListAsync().

Comment: @NickitaDavidenko реального ускорения можно достичь только отказом от вызова базы вообще. LotTypes меняются редко или вообще никогда? положите их в кэш - локальный, если не меняются вообще, или распределенный (напримерRedis?) - если меняются редко.

Answer (score 0):

Ну проблема в том, что Вы пытаетесь вернуть не типизированную **задачу**, а объект типа **ActionResult**, о чём Вам и пишет компилятор. Для этого функция, извлекающая результат, а именно Steps(), должна быть асинхронной и возвращать тоже (и не удивительно!) задачу! Как сделать обычную функцию асинхронной я писать не буду.