# Оптимизация работы с SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, инспекция-кода, ado.net

Имеется код (он рабочий), но хотел бы узнать, можно его как-то упростить? Особенно интересует, можно как-нибудь уменьшить кол-во строк? Просто из-за использования `using`, блоков исключения и т.д код растягивается, теряется читабельность.

Пожалуйста, ответьте как можно понятнее для новичка :)

```
public partial class CreateAds : Form
{
    public MainForm otherForm;
    string pathBase = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "ads.db");

    public CreateAds(MainForm form1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        otherForm = form1;

        btCreate.Click += (sender, e) => {
            if (!File.Exists(pathBase)) 
            {
                SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(pathBase);
                using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(string.Format("Data Source={0};", pathBase))) 
                {
                    using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("CREATE TABLE `base` (ID integer primary key, Name varchar, DateCreate varchar, DateEnd varchar, Mesto tinyint(5));", con)) 
                    {
                        try 
                        {
                            con.Open();
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex) 
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                        }
                        finally 
                        {
                            con.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(string.Format("Data Source={0};", pathBase)))
            {
                try
                {
                    con.Open();

                    string query = string.Format("INSERT INTO 'base' ('Name', 'DateCreate', 'DateEnd', 'Mesto') VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}');", tbName.Text, tbDateCreate.Text, tbDateEnd.Text, tbMesto.Value);

                    using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, con))
                    {
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
            otherForm.dgv.Rows.Add(tbName.Text, tbDateCreate.Text, tbDateEnd.Text, tbMesto.Value, "Удалить");
        };
    }
}
```

```html
public static async Task InsertBase(string Names, string DateCreates, string DateEnds, decimal Mestos)
        {
            string pathBase = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "ads.db");

            using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(string.Format("Data Source={0};", pathBase)))
            {
                await con.OpenAsync();

                string query = string.Format("INSERT INTO 'base' ('Name', 'DateCreate', 'DateEnd', 'Mesto') VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}');", Names, DateCreates, DateEnds, Mestos);

                using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, con))
                {
                    await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Лямбду делают <= ~7 строк, а если невозможно, то тогда делают метод, который вызывают из лямбды. И почему нельзя было сразу метод подписать на событие? Зачем городить такое? А про асинхронность вы слышали?

Comment: Using не закрывает соединение ?

Comment: @Bulson, не думал что так много строк выйдет. Про асинхронность слышал.. можете конкретно указать что не так?

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk, т.е, вы имеете ввиду, соединение автоматически закрывается при выходе из блока using?

Comment: Судя по коду у вас приложение WinForms. Соединение с БД будет блокировать UI-поток. Лучше делать асинхронно такие операции

Comment: @Максим да, но я не уверен будет ли оно закрыто при exception

Comment: Использование `using` предполагает, что руками прописывать `Close` не нужно, т.к. класс реализует `IDisposable`

Answer (score 1):

`SQLiteConnection con` следует сделать `private` полем класса, да и откровенно говоря, работу с БД нужно выносить в отдельный класс `Repository`, совсем выносить, подальше от UI.

SQLite - локальная БД, соединение в принципе можно держать открытым на протяжении всего времени работы программы. Программа запустилась, соединение установили, при закрытии программы закрываем соединение.

Создайте интерфейс со всеми требуемыми методами: create, read, update, delete и используйте его как тип для поля через которое будете работать с классом `Repository`.

Методы в `Repository` нужно сделать асинхронными, для этого создаете обычные синхронные методы, проверяете как работают (тестируете), а потом делаете так:

```
//предположим у нас есть синхронный метод
public bool DeleteEntity(int id) {...}

//делаем ему асинхронного брата
public Task<bool> DeleteEntityAsync(int id)
{
     return Task.Run<bool>(() =>
     {
         return DeleteEntity(id);
     });
}
```

Тогда в нужном месте мы сможем вызвать его так

```
bool result = await _repository.DeleteEntityAsync(123);
```

Comment: Спасибо! А мой код сильно плох по сравнению с вашим? (Я прикрепил его в первый пост)

Comment: [Не нужно](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/498404/106) создавать "асинхронных братьев".

Comment: @andreycha там речь про API, и про то, что надо дать пользователям этого API самим определять, как запускать синхронные методы. Здесь совсем другой случай. Не надо впадать в мракобесие, кто-то чего-то там порекомендовал, может и вполне разумное, в данном конкретном случае, но не надо слепо следовать данной рекомендации, и становится этаким адептом, проводником истины в последней инстанции.

Comment: Публичные методы репозитория и есть его API. А UI (или другой слой) -- клиент этого API. Поэтому позвольте клиенту самому решать, как запускать метод.

Comment: @andreycha, спасибо, что обратили мое внимание на данную проблему. Но вот в данном конкретном случае, парень пишет небольшую программу, и сам знает, что у него синхронное, а что является всего лишь асинхронной оберткой. Поэтому я не пойму в чем проблема? То ли он это синхронный метод обернет в UI в Task.Run(), то ли он это сделает заранее в репозитории, и добавит тем самым лаконичности в код UI. Ну, что тут криминального!?

Comment: Парень пишет небольшую программу и сам знает, где у него обращение к БД, а где к интерфейсу, зачем ему репозиторий? ;) Правила сначала лучше выучить, выполнять, а только потом учиться нарушать.

Comment: Если я правильно понял принципы работы async/await, то в представленном коде они, собственно, бесполезны?