# Постоянно возвращать Task или при необходимости использовать Task.Run()?

Tags: c#, многопоточность, async-await, асинхронность

Есть вот такой класс из слоя бизнес-логики:

```
public class ProductService
{
    private readonly IGenericRepository<Product> _productRepository;

    public ProductService(IGenericRepository<Product> productRepository)
    {
        _productRepository = productRepository;
    }

    public Task Update(int id, ProductModel model)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            if (model == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(model));
            }

            var product = _productRepository.GetById(id);
            if (product == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(nameof(id));
            }
            // еще код... //

            _productRepository.Update(product);
        });
    }
}
```

Я поймал себя на том, что у меня все методы, обращающиеся к базе данных *(даже если они обращаются через репозитории)*, возвращают `Task`, так как знаю, что выше у меня Web API контроллер, action которого я хочу вызывать асинхронно.

Я думаю, что я делаю неправильно, потому что, проектируя класс `ProductService` я не должен заботиться о клиентском коде. Сейчас да, у меня клиентом является самый верхний слой (Web API), но так ведь может быть не всегда и для другого клиента возможно тип `Task` метода `Update` может быть излишним. **Я прав?**

---

Согласно своим рассуждениям я переписал метод`ProductService.Update()` и класс-клиент:

```
public void Update(int id, ProductModel model)
{
    if (model == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(model));
    }

    var product = _productRepository.GetById(id);
    if (product == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(nameof(id));
    }
    // еще код... //

    _productRepository.Update(product);
}


[RoutePrefix("api/products")]
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IProductService _productService;

    public ProductsController(IProductService productService)
    {
        _productService = productService;
    }

    [HttpPut]
    [Route("{id:int}")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put([FromBody] productModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var productId = (int)RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"];

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            _productService.Update(productId, productModel);
        });

        return Ok();
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В том что вы делаете, нет ни малейшего смысла - методы контроллеров уже исполняются в пуле потоков, и выносить их снова в пул потоков через `Task.Run` -
 бесполезно.

Если вам хочется сделать полностью асинхронный код - надо отказаться от `Task.Run` в пользу действительно асинхронных способов. Так, если вы используете EntityFramework, то вытащить запись из БД можно через [`FirstOrDefaultAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220208(v=vs.113).aspx), а сохранить изменения - через [`SaveChangesAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dn220070(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: Вы хотите сказать, что при запросе клиента к `ProductsControlers.Put()` автоматически создается отдельная нить `ProductsControlers.Put() -> ProductService.Update() -> GenericRepoisoty<Product>.Update()`?

Comment: @adamshakhabov такая нить создавалась бы, если бы вы не делали `await Task.Run`. Сейчас у вас используются две разные нити для той же цели.

Comment: Ох не зря я засомневался, что у меня тут какая-то муть). Значить, оставляю второй вариант `ProductService.Update()`, убираю `async/await/Task.Run()` из `ProductsController.Put()` и каждый запрос клиента на обновление сущности `Product` будет выполняться асинхронно, так?

Comment: @adamshakhabov вам надо в любом случае убрать **все** Task.Run, у вас оба варианта неправильные.

Comment: @adamshakhabov никаких Task.Run в коде быть вообще не должно если только вы намеренно не параллелите свой код.

Answer (score 4):

> Я думаю, что я делаю неправильно, потому что, проектируя класс
>   ProductService я не должен заботиться о клиентском коде.

Совершенно верно. Предоставьте возможность клиенту самому решать, когда ему запускать метод синхронно, а когда -- асинхронно. Создание асинхронных оберток для синхронных методов [мы уже обсуждали](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/498404/106).