# Выполнение синхронного кода в async методе

Tags: c#, async-await

Есть у меня promise метод чтения данных из моего потока:

```
public void ReadAsync<T>(AsyncReadCallback<T> callback, AsyncException exception = null) {
    try {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => {
            try {
                T request = ReadSync<T>();
                callback.Invoke(ref request);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                if(exception == null) {
                    throw e;
                }
                exception.Invoke(e);
            }
        }));
        thread.Start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if(exception == null) {
            throw e;
        }
        exception.Invoke(e);
    }
}
```

Вызывать я его могу, соответственно так:

```
stream.ReadAsync((string result) => {
    Console.WriteLine("receive: "+result);
},(Exception e) => {
    Console.WriteLine("exception: "+e.Message);
});
```

---

Но, в погоне за сахаром, решил попробовать сделать аналогичное поведение через async, что даст возможность выполнять всё без потоков, более того, заставлять делать await в нужных мне местах:

```
public async Task<T> ReadAsync<T>() {
    return ReadSync<T>();
}
```

Вызывать планирую, примерно так:

```
Task<string> taskRead = stream.ReadAsync<string>();
...
string data = await taskRead;
Console.WriteLine(data);
```

Однако, VS2017 говорит, что мой код будет выполняться только синхронно, и что там нет await. Я не могу понять, возможно ли вообще то что я задумал?

Вот что говорит сама студия (скрин очень неудобный):
[image: Скрин]
Всё что я хочу - выполнять синхронный метод так, как если бы он был асинхронен. (Возможно, звучит глупо, но, не могу сформулировать по другому)

Comment: Ключевое слово `async` используется в тех методах, внутри которых есть `await`. В вашем методе `ReadAsync` await'ов нет

Comment: @tym32167, Поясните, то есть, эту задачу можно решать исключительно потоками?

Comment: Вам нужно понять, что асинхронный код != многопоточный код, и все сразу станет яснее :)

Comment: @tym32167, Вы хотите сказать, что в асинхронности не важен только порядок? Я представлю async, как нечто отдалённо напоминающее короутину. Возможно, поэтому заблуждаюсь.

Comment: Я хочу сказать, что возможно написать асинхронный код, который не задействует многопоточность.

Comment: Привяжу: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/491783/106 и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/498418/106

Comment: @andreycha, Огромное Спасибо! Целая куча полезной информации!

Comment: @test123 не за что!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ключевое слово `async` позволяет выполнять асинхронное ожидание других задач (делать `await`), но простое добавление этого слова ничего не дает вам в плане многопоточности. Перемещение выполнения в другой поток все еще остается именно вашей задачей.

Выполнить задачу в фоновом потоке можно при помощи `Task.Run`:

```
public Task<T> ReadAsync<T>() {
    return Task.Run(() => ReadSync<T>());
}
```

Однако, написание подобных оберток является дурной практикой: от асинхронного кода ожидается что он по крайней мере часть своей работы выполнит не занимая потока.

Вероятно, правильным будет не делать отдельного метода `ReadAsync` - а вставить конструкцию `Task.Run(() => ReadSync<T>())` непосредственно в том месте где вам нужно прочитать данные:

```
Task<string> taskRead = Task.Run(() => stream.ReadSync<T>());
...
string data = await taskRead;
Console.WriteLine(data);
```

А еще правильнее - переписать метод `ReadSync` так, чтобы он стал асинхронным.

Comment: Спасибо! То что нужно. Не с проста я сомневался в том что всё настолько просто... Значит, никакой магии за async не стоит :(

Comment: @test123 еще как стоит. Но связана она исключительно со словом `await`.